# BASH how to save output of rm with timestamp?

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script

I nearly have this working, This is a script that will run in CRON to keep the latest 10 backups, and remove anything else, I want to log this to keep track to make sure all is in good order, I have it working & writing what files were deleted, alas I cannot set a prefix of a timestamp.

```
TIMESTAMP=$(date +%d-%m-%Y-%H-%M-%S)
LOGFILE="/home/user/place/backups/backuplog.txt"
echo "$TIMESTAMP, " | ls -1tr | head -n -10 | xargs -d '\n' rm -f -v >> $LOGFILE
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the output you would like to have. `echo foo | ls` doesn't make any sense so we can't understand what you would like to see. Also, this will fail if your file names can contain whitespace (or other strangeness), can you be _sure_ that your file names will always be sane? If so, mention that in your edit as well.

Comment: Maybe all you need is `echo -n` to not get a linebreak between time and log?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `ts` command for that:

`ts [-r] [-i | -s] [format]`

Something like the following:

```bash
TS_FORMAT="%d-%m-%Y-%H-%M-%S, "
LOGFILE="/home/user/place/backups/backuplog.txt"
ls -1tr | head -n -10 | xargs -d '\n' rm -f -v | ts "${TS_FORMAT}" >> $LOGFILE
```

`ts` is included in the [`moreutils`](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/) package.

#### Update: Without Installing More Dependecies

You can use `xargs` again:

```bash
TIMESTAMP=$(date +%d-%m-%Y-%H-%M-%S)
LOGFILE="/home/user/place/backups/backuplog.txt"
ls -1tr | head -n -10 | xargs -d '\n' rm -f -v | xargs -L 1 -d '\n' echo "${TIMESTAMP}, " >> $LOGFILE
```

Another possibility is to use `sed`:

```bash
TIMESTAMP=$(date +%d-%m-%Y-%H-%M-%S)
LOGFILE="/home/user/place/backups/backuplog.txt"
ls -1tr | head -n -10 | xargs -d '\n' rm -f -v | sed "s/^/${TIMESTAMP}/" >> $LOGFILE
```

Using `awk`:

```bash
LOGFILE="/home/user/place/backups/backuplog.txt"
ls -1tr | head -n -10 | xargs -d '\n' rm -f -v | awk '{ print strftime("%d-%m-%Y-%H-%M-%S"), $0}' >> $LOGFILE
```

And so on.

Comment: Thats cool, but could this still be done without installing any more dependencies? I.e im happy with my current timestamp, I just need it to put that variable before the verbose output of rm i.e it records any files that were deleted with a timestamp.

Comment: Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest a loop based approach for this question (although we are all into one-liners) , ots also better for readability. Of course in CRON just call to this script file instead of executing the code there directly:

```
strings=`ls -1tr | head -n -10`
for file in $strings; do
      rmOutput=`rm -f -v $file`
      echo `date +%d-%m-%Y-%M-%S`: $rmOutput >> $LOGFILE
 done
```